# Facebook Same Window Authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to do Facebook authentication in same window of my web application's login page.
I am using following code when user clicked login button to go to authentication page.

```
function loginUsingOAUTH()
{   
    top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=839846246064537&scope=email&redirect_uri=http://www.olcayertas.com/testqa/result.html';
}
```

1) After authentication Facebook redirects me to my redirect url and returns a parameter "code".
At this point I want to access Facebook user information but I don't know how to do that.
What is this "code" parameter for?

2) Is there any other way to access user information?

3) Do you have any other advice facebook authentication with same window login?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you get the code you should make a server side request to get an access token and than pass the access token to user. It is explained in Facebook Developer page:

> **Exchanging code for an access token**
>
> To get an access token, make an HTTP GET request to the following
>   OAuth endpoint:
>
> ```
> GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token?
>     client_id={app-id}
>    &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
>    &client_secret={app-secret}
>    &code={code-parameter}
> ```
>
> This endpoint has some required parameters:
>
> ```
> client_id. Your app's IDs
> redirect_uri. This argument is required and must be the same as the original request_uri that you used when starting the OAuth login
> ```
>
> process.
>       client_secret. Your unique app secret, shown on the App Dashboard. This app secret should never be included in client-side code or in
>   binaries that could be decompiled. It is extremely important that it
>   remains completely secret as it is the core of the security of your
>   app and all the people using it.
>       code. The parameter received from the Login Dialog redirect above.
>
> **Response**
>
> The response you will receive from this endpoint will be returned in
>   JSON format and, if successful, is
>
> ```
> {“access_token”: <access-token>, “token_type”:<type>, “expires_in”:<seconds-til-expiration>}
> ```
>
> If it is not successful, you will receive an explanatory error
>   message.